# VB.Net Menu strip hover

Tags: vb.net, vb6, menustrip

I have these menu in my form but when I hover on the disabled item and continue to the next enabled item, sub menus stop from showing...Is this the new default behavior of vb.net? Because in vb6 sub menus will still continue to show. Please help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have sub menu for help to hover?

Comment: @  TipidPack : you are right same problem occurs for me  also, Use arrow keys for selection i works properly,

Comment: Well I guest thats it, vb.net has also some limitation to vb6. Thanks anyways @SujithKarivelil

Comment: @TipidPack, it's not really a limitation, but rather just a different behaviour.  If that's how it behaves then it's nothing specifically to do with VB.NET.  It's the .NET Framework.  The same behaviour would be seen if your app was written in C#, C++/CLI or .NET Delphi.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I see..well at least I know now their difference. Thanks!